# Use of asymptotic notation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

[image: Question-based on asymptotic notation]

---

I have a doubt in this particular question where the answer says that big-Oh(n^2) algorithm will not run faster than big-Oh(n^3) algorithm whereas if the notation in both cases was theta instead then it would have been true but why is that so?

I would love it if anyone could explain it to me in detail because I couldn't find any source from where my doubt could get clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 paraphrased (note the phrasing in the question is ambiguous where "number" is quantified -- it has to be picked *after* you choose the two algorithms, but I assume that's what's intended).

> Given functions f and g with f=Theta(n^2) and g=Theta(n^3), then there exists a number N such that f(n) < g(n) for all n>N.

Part 2 paraphrased:

> Given functions f and g with f=O(n^2) and g=O(n^3), then for all n, f(n) < g(n).

1 is true, and you can prove it by application of the definition of big-Theta.

2 is false (as a general statement), and you can disprove it by finding a single example of f and g for which it is false. For example, f(n) = 2, g(n) = 1. Big O is a kind of upper bound, so these constant functions work. The counter-examples given in the question are f(n)=n, g(n)=log(n), but the same principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

> the answer says that big-Oh(n^2) algorithm will not run faster than big-Oh(n^3) algorithm

It is more subtle: an O(²) algorithm *could* run slower than a O(³) algorithm. It is not *will*, but *could*.

The answer gives one reason, but actually there are two:

1. Big O notation only gives an *upper* bound. Quoted from Wikipedia:

   > A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function.

   So anything that is O() is also O(²) and O(³), but not necessarily vice versa. The answer says that an algorithm that is O(³) could maybe have a tighter bound that is O(log). True, this may sound silly, because why should one then say it is O(³) when it is also O(log)? Then it seems more reasonable to just talk about O(log). And this is what we commonly do. But there is also a second reason:
2. The second option does not have the contraint *"n > number"* in its claim. This is essential, because irrespective of time complexities, the running time of an algorithm for a given value of  *cannot* be determined from its time complexity. An algorithm that is O(log) may take 10 seconds to do its job, while an algorithm that is O(²) may take 8 seconds to get the same result, even though its time complexity is worse. When comparing time complexities you only get information about *asymptotic* behaviour, i.e. when  is larger than a large enough number.

   Because this extra constraint is part of the first claim, it is indeed true.

Comment: I understood the 1st reason but I am not clear with the second reason that you have written. I think I get why statement 2 is false in the question but why 1st one is correct is still vague to me. Kindly guide me with your knowledge.

Comment: This follows from the *definition* of big O. Check the [formal definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), where x0 is the constant "number" mentioned in option 1. I gave a concrete example in my answer that should illustrate this point.